# How to have a different section for a special category of posts in landing page?

Tags: featured-post

I wish to have a different section for a certain category of posts displayed in the landing page of my WordPress website, while posts of various other categories display in an other section.

Is this possible in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you will need to create another loop for that special category using WP_Query class. An example of a loop returning the "cats" category would be:

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'category_name'          => 'cats',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // do something
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Depending on the number of sections on your landing page, you will have multiple loops, but do not forget to reset each loop on the page.

Comment: wow I'm not that into programming or coding. Thanks though. Where do I insert this or a similar snippet? :)

Comment: probably in index.php?

Comment: It goes into template your landing page uses. If not using any custom Page template, then index.php is likely the template you are using for the home (landing) page.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is definitely possible. You basically you need to do is combine multiple loops with custom loop queries, more info can be found here: [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

```
 <?php $query = new WP_Query( 'cat=CATEGORY ID YOU WANT TO DISPLAY HERE' ); ?>
 <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

    OUTPUT HTML HERE

 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

 <?php rewind_posts(); ?>

<?php $query = new WP_Query( 'cat=2ND CATEGORY ID YOU WANT TO DISPLAY HERE' ); ?>
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

    OUTPUT HTML HERE

 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Remember the rewind_posts() method to get this to work properly

Comment: can't thank you enough. thanks. I will try to work it out now, myself.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your comment on another answer "wow I'm not that into programming or coding." so I figured I'd chime in with another option.

If you're using Elementor or Divi or another similar visual builder, they generally will have a module for blog posts that you can filter by category, which allows you to create a section on a page of posts within a certain category or categories without the need to add code to your site.

For example, in Divi there is a module that allows this that looks the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/248398)

Comment: I didn't ask any questions.